# Sqlite files with numbers doesn't work in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing an app that uses sqlite database, and I am storing them in the assets folder.

I need the files to have descriptive numbers(like db_42_2_43_3.sqlite) but they don't work, I understood that this limitation is present with the files inside the res/raw folder (file names without capital letters, without numbers greater than 9, etc) but these files are not there, They are in the assets folder.

Note: the app works with filenames without numbers greater than 9 (as if the file would be in the res/raw folder)

Any suggestion? This is my SqlLiteDbHelper class

```
public class SqlLiteDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public String DATABASE_NAME;

    private static final String DB_PATH_SUFFIX = "/databases/";
    static Context ctx;

    public SqlLiteDbHelper(Context context, String db_filename) {
        super(context, db_filename, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ctx = context;
        DATABASE_NAME = db_filename;
    }

    public ArrayList<Poi> getDetails(double lat, double lng, double radius) {//radius in meters
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<Poi> poiList = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM puentes";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Poi cont = new Poi(cursor.getLong(0), cursor.getLong(1), cursor.getDouble(2), cursor.getDouble(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(6));
                poiList.add(cont);
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

        }
        return poiList;
    }

    public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = ctx.getAssets().open(DB_PATH_SUFFIX + DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName = getDatabasePath();
        
        File f = new File(ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
        if (!f.exists())
            f.mkdir();
        
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    private String getDatabasePath() {
        return ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX + DATABASE_NAME;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        File dbFile = ctx.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            try {
                CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
                System.out.println("Copying sucess from Assets folder");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
            }
        }
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Conusing code. You should throw away that getDatabasePath() function. After that: File outFile = new File(f, fileName). Then use outFile to open the outputstream.

Comment: `need the files to have descriptive numbers(like db_42_2_43_3.sqlite) but they don't work` Dont believe you. File names are not a problem i would say. But be cannot even see that you try to use such a name. You should be able to copy them from assets to file system to begin with.  And we dont know what you consider to be 'dont work'.